# Conditional replacement of a string using regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to replace all occurrences of `@example/` in a file, unless the complete match is `@example/is`.

Currently I have this code:

```
 let updated = s.replace(/@example\//g, replacement);
```

However this will update all occurrences, including the ones with `@example/is`. How do we exclude the `@example/is` occurrences in the file?

### Addendum

I'm just pasting in the script I used (which incorporates the great answer) to perform the updates, in case anyone else needs to do something like this:

```
const fs = require("fs");
const globby = require("globby");
globby("./test/**/*.ts")
  .then(paths => {
    paths.forEach(update);
  })
  .catch(e => console.log(e));

function update(path) {
  let replacement = "@ex/";
  let js = fs.readFileSync(path, "utf8");
  js = js.replace(/@example\/(?!is)/g, replacement)
  fs.writeFileSync(path, js);
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a [negative lookahead assertion](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
let updated = s.replace(/@example\/(?!is)/g, replacement)
```

`(?!is)` is a negative lookahead assertion that will fail the match when `is` comes after `@example/`